# I would like to reword this sentence. I do not like "of" at the end of sentence

Tags: prepositions

You have taken the responsibility of student attendance and its accounting system, producing reports that all stakeholders can sense the importance of.

Comment: ...producing reports whose importance all stakeholders can sense.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  1.  In U.K. education language one would undertake the responsibility FOR something.  2.  I do not understand what an accounting system has to do with attendance:  is payment made only when students attend?; or are they fined for not attending?  3.  What is the thing of which ‘stakeholders’ must see the importance?  Is it attendance?  Or is it the reports?

Comment: Ending sentences with prepositions is not something to be afraid of.

Comment: The _of_ at the end of the sentence seems completely natural. Moving it around will only serve to make people think you believe in some non-existing weird rule that no sensible person wants to adhere to.

Comment: Ending a sentence with 'of' is not something to be afraid of.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the right way to change the least amount of the sentence is:

"You have taken the responsibility of student attendance and its accounting system, producing reports of which all stakeholders can sense the importance."

Or:

"You have taken the responsibility of student attendance and its accounting system, producing reports the importance of which all stakeholders can sense."

@Tuffy Just because it's an "accounting" system doesn't mean that money is exchanging hands. If it's a school they have to "account" for who's there and who's not on a given day.

RE: stakeholders, maybe it's a private school, and attendance is one way that they can show investors that it (the school) is worth their money.

Sorry, can't comment yet; otherwise, I would have.

Comment: I prefer the original version as being slightly clearer (and equally grammatical).

Comment: What's wrong with the hanging 'of'? It's perfectly correct. As are the two alternatives  given in this answer. But as Edwin says, your original sentence is clearer.

Comment: I'm not saying I like my version, I'm just saying those are the different versions that require the least amount of change.